# font size on the iphone

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

I'm using the following email template (I chose the basic one) from zurb

http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates
http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-email-templates/basic.html

which includes the following media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}
    div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}
    table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
    }
}
```

the font on the phone looks really small specifically the text inside the table cells is so tiny

How to override the font on the phone?

Comment: It looks fine on my iphone.  But if you do want it bigger.  Can you please post what/if anything that you've tried so far?

Comment: I manually put  td {font-size: 15px!important;} inside the query but of course it didn't work

Comment: Since it's Foundation, are you using Sass or do you only have the compiled email.css file?

Comment: I just used the css file in the email template just like what they did.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing you could do is go through the file and change all font-sizes from px to em.  However, 1em is equal to 12px, so you will have to do some math to get the numbers right.  Then, you can add a style to the body {font-size: 120%;} and that will change the font size to 120% of what it would normally be.  You can change it to any percentage that you like and it will change all of the fonts based on the em value you gave each element.  Then, if you want to change all of the font sizes at once, you just change that percentage...then you don't lose you proportions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56982/discussion-between-joshboley-and-nemo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best thing you could do is go through the file and change all font-sizes from px to em. However, 1em is equal to 12px, so you will have to do some math to get the numbers right. Then, you can add a style to the

`body {font-size: 120%;}`

and that will change the font size to 120% of what it would normally be. You can change it to any percentage that you like and it will change all of the fonts based on the em value you gave each element. Then, if you want to change all of the font sizes at once, you just change that percentage...then you don't lose you proportions.  You can also leave the desktop the same by adding font-size:100% to the body element. Then, in the media query, you can set the body font-size to something like 120%.